# Getting Volley.ServerError while making a JSONObjectRequest to an IP with a PORT

Tags: android, android-volley, jsonobjectrequest

I have seen many blogs and links but couldn't find a satisfactory answer. I am making a simple *POST* request *(JSONObjectRequest)* using volley in my application but getting **com.android.volley.ServerError** in volley error. The URL I am using is "http://192.XXX.X.XX:8080/zin-pushnotification_stage/pushnotification/service/register". Is it possible that volley does not support urls having port numbers in it? Need a simple and precise solution.

**Code:**

```
Map<String, String> body = new HashMap<>();
body.put("deviceId", "STECH-1502878253");
body.put("token", "XYZ");
body.put("deviceType", "IPHONE");
body.put("companyKey", "STECH");
JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,"http://192.XXX.X.XX:8080/zin-pushnotification_stage/pushnotification/service/register", new JSONObject(body), new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                Log.e("Data response", response);
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e("VolleyError","Error response", error);
            }
        }) {
            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> header = new HashMap<>();
                header.put("Content-Type", ApplicationConstants.Content_Type);
                header.put("Authorization", ApplicationConstants.CUSTOM_AUTH_TOKEN);
                return header;
            }
        };

        requestQueue.add(request);
```

**Stack Trace:**

```
E/Volley: [35860] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 400 for http://192.XXX.X.XX:8080/zin-pushnotification_stage/pushnotification/service/register
W/System.err: com.android.volley.ServerError
W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:163)
W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:112)
```

Comment: We need your simple and precise relevant code and full logcat stacktrace of the error

Comment: can you please add more details

Comment: Updated my post

Comment: Can you also post a sample response from the url: `"http://192.XXX.X.XX:8080/pushnotificaitons_staging/` ?

Comment: for your staging url, if your code is not on live server, then your app and the server should be connected to same network for it to work.

Comment: You code and the stacktrace URLs are not the same: 1) `http://192.XXX.X.XX:8080/zin-pushnotification_stage/pushnotification/service/register` and 2) `http://192.XXX.X.XX:8080/pushnotification_stage/`

Comment: @VivekMishra I am accessing it from same network. The app and server are on same network

Comment: @pleft . Sorry my bad. That's typo error. The url is: "http://192.XXX.X.XX:8080/zin-pushnotification_stage/pushnoti‌​fication/service/reg‌​ister"

Comment: 400 means generally means bad request. Are you missing some parameters in your request. Try your api on postman first whether it is working or not

Comment: Yes, tried it in postman and its working. No I am not missing any params.

Comment: Inside your `notifyError` can you add the following line: `Log.e("TAG", "Error response:", error);` and post again the related logcat stacktrace?

Comment: @pleft. It's the same as above:
E/VolleyError: Error response:
                                                                               com.android.volley.ServerError
                                                                                   at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:163)
                                                                                   at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:112)

Comment: `new JSONObject(body)`. what is this `body` variable? can you show it to us? Moreover this `WebServiceManagert` looks like custom class, couldn't find it in the `Android` `API`, do you mind if you also post the code of it? If you want your error resolved you have to provide as much info as possible

Comment: @pleft Updated my code . Kindly check.

Comment: Ok, can you also check for errors on your server? update your answer accordingly.

Comment: Also what's the value of `ApplicationConstants.Content_Type` ?

Comment: "application/json" @pleft

Comment: Can you try to change it to `"application/json; charset=utf-8"` or even completely remove `header.put("Content-Type", ApplicationConstants.Content_Type);` ?

Comment: @pleft .. Thank you. The issue is fixed by removing the content type all together but what does this indicate ? That my body params were not in JSON format ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JsonObjectRequest` extends `JsonRequest`. If you take a look at the source code of [`JsonRequest`](https://github.com/google/volley/blob/master/src/main/java/com/android/volley/toolbox/JsonRequest.java) you will spot:

```
 /** Default charset for JSON request. */
protected static final String PROTOCOL_CHARSET = "utf-8";

/** Content type for request. */
private static final String PROTOCOL_CONTENT_TYPE =
String.format("application/json; charset=%s", PROTOCOL_CHARSET);

@Override
    public String getBodyContentType() {
        return PROTOCOL_CONTENT_TYPE;
}
```

So `JsonObjectRequest` by **default** sets the `content-type` header to `application/json; charset=utf-8`. What you did was to also send another header for `content-type` which caused the server response with status `400`. Removing the extra header by deleting the line:

```
header.put("Content-Type", ApplicationConstants.Content_Type);
```

made the request to include only the default header which was the correct one.

Comment: Although I do have other API's where I am sending content-type in headers with JSONObjectRequest and they are working then how come this doesn't work ?

Comment: I don't know your applications, maybe your api server side code accepts those headers, http status 400 means that the server could not understand the request so I guess it depends on the server side code what to accept as valid request or what not. For the specific case the custom header you set was not expected by your server.